# How loops are implemented in PIC24F assembly code

Tags: assembly, pic, instruction-set, pic24, dspic

Below is the disassembly of following C code:

```
268:                   while (Counter < 250)
269:                   {
270:                       Counter++;
271:                   }
```

Disassembly:

```
268:                   while (Counter < 250)
001B08  370003     BRA 0x1B10
001B10  90406E     MOV.B [W14+6], W0
001B12  404FE7     ADD.B W0, #0x7, [W15]
001B14  36FFFA     BRA LEU, 0x1B0A
269:                   {
270:                       Counter++;
001B0A  90406E     MOV.B [W14+6], W0
001B0C  E84000     INC.B W0, W0
001B0E  984760     MOV.B W0, [W14+6]
271:                   }
272:                   
273:                   // call foo
274:                   foo(LAT, 4, Set, &Code);
001B16  203F20     MOV #0x3F2, W0
001B18  40000E     ADD W0, W14, W0
001B1A  780180     MOV W0, W3
001B1C  B3C012     MOV.B #0x1, W2
001B1E  B3C041     MOV.B #0x4, W1
001B20  202C40     MOV #0x2C4, W0
001B22  0709C7     RCALL foo
```

Couldn't able to understand how the while loop has been achieved.
Assume that [W14+6] refers to location RAM where `Counter` is stored.

Note: The code generated for PIC24FV32KA304

Comment: I'm guessing there may be a few more asm lines below `271:                   }` to jump back into the loop.

Comment: Apparently no. Anyhow, updated the question to add lines below 271.

Comment: Hmm, the compiler could be optimising out the count perhaps? What do you get if the code is only the loop, or if you compile without any optimisation?

Comment: Where are the lines: 001BA, 001BC and 001BE?

Comment: @msbit I see this issue wherever there is a loop in the code. I don't have a compiler to experiment. I have C files and corresponding disassembly file.

Comment: @Mike do you mean `001B0A`, `001B0C`, and `001B0E`?

Comment: @msbit Yes, sorry I was too fast!

Comment: @Mike now I understand how the loop has been achieved. Thanks.

Comment: @msbit Thank you.

Comment: @MSharathHegde good, now could you fill me in? I'm still wondering how it's looping :)

Comment: @MSharathHegde ah now I see, the disassembly was out of order

Comment: @msbit At 0x01B08 instruction is to branch to 0x1B10. 0x1B10 isn't the next address after 0x01B08; 001B0A comes after 0x01B08. At 0x1B10, the check happens (if Counter < 250), if true again branches to 0x01B0A. Subsequently execution again goes to 0x1B10 and the loop continues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It has changed the order of your code your code to something like:

```
GOTO A
B:  Counter++;
A:  if (Counter <= 249) GOTO B
```

Here is the reordered assembly with my comments:

```
001B08  370003     BRA 0x1B10               // GOTO A
                         B: Counter++;
001B0A  90406E     MOV.B [W14+6], W0        // Copy Counter to W0
001B0C  E84000     INC.B W0, W0             // Increment W0
001B0E  984760     MOV.B W0, [W14+6]        // Put W0 back in Counter
                         A:  if (Counter <= 249) GOTO B
001B10  90406E     MOV.B [W14+6], W0        // Get counter to W0
001B12  404FE7     ADD.B W0, #0x7, [W15]    // Add 7 in modulo 256.
                                            // This is the same as subtracting 249
001B14  36FFFA     BRA LEU, 0x1B0A          // if result <= 0 GOTO B
                                            // else just drop through to code below
```

`BRA LEU` is the key looping instruction here. It means **BRA**nch if **L**ess than or **E**qual **U**nsigned. This means the branch is taken if C=0 or Z=1 as left by the previous instruction.

A detail that it is easy to get confused about is that `C`, is the *carry* flag after addition. But if, as in this example, we want to regard the `ADD` as a subtraction then you should treat `not(C)` as *borrow*. That's why `BRA LEU` takes the branch if C=0.